# Append HTML into div using Angular 5 / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I want to append some HTML content inside a div using angular 5 and typescript.

Here is my div where i want to append `<div class = "parent">`

Here is my HTML content which i want to append -->
***component.html***

```
<div #notification class="notification-top-bar" [ngClass]="type" style="display: block;"> 
</div>
```

I don't have any access to modify `<div class = "parent"></div>`.

Here is my ***component.ts***

```
export class SiteNotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChildren('notification') private notificationsElements:  QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Want to do something like this-->

```
var d1 = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div #notification class="notification-top-bar" [ngClass]="type" style="display: block;"></div>');
```

Comment: Well, add `<div class = "parent">` inside the div. If you only want this inner div to appear in certain conditions, use *ngIf. If you want several ones to appear, use *ngFor. Your question is a bit unclear, and it seems like you reason in terms of DOM modifications, instead of reasoning in terms of component templates which display stuff based on the model they're bound to.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called dynamic component loading.

I suggest you take a look at [this example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) from the official website